# Mixing ActiveRecord find Conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to find records on a combination of created_on >= some date AND name IN some list of names.

For ">=" I'd have to use sql condition. For "IN" I'd have to use a hash of conditions where the key is :name and the value is the array of names.

Is there a way to combine the two?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use named scopes in rails 2.1 and above

```
Class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :created_after_2005, :conditions => "created_on > 2005-01-01"
  named_scope :named_fred, :conditions => { :name => "fred"}
end
```

then you can do

```
Test.created_after_2005.named_fred
```

Or you can give named_scope a lambda allowing you to pass in arguments

```
Class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :created_after, lambda { |date| {:conditions => ["created_on > ?", date]} }
  named_scope :named, lambda { |name| {:conditions => {:name => name}} }
end
```

then you can do

```
Test.created_after(Time.now-1.year).named("fred")
```

Answer (score 8):

If you're using an older version Rails, Honza's query is close, but you need to add parentheses for the strings that get placed in the IN condition:

```
Person.find(:all, :conditions => ["created_at > ? AND name IN (?)", date, names])
```

Using IN can be a mixed bag: it's fastest for integers and slowest for a list of strings.  If you find yourself using just one name, definitely use an equals operator:

```
Person.find(:all, :conditions => ["created_at > ? AND name = ?", date, name])
```

Answer (score 3):

The cool thing about named_scopes is that they work on collections too:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :published, :conditions => {:status => 'published'}
end

@post = Post.published

@posts = current_user.posts.published
```

Answer (score 2):

For more on named_scopes see [Ryan's announcement](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/3/24/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-has-finder-functionality) and the [Railscast on named_scopes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/108)

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :registered, lambda { |time_ago| { :conditions => ['created_at > ?', time_ago] } }
  named_scope :with_names, lambda { |names| { :conditions => { :names => names } } }
end
```

If you are going to pass in variables to your scopes you have to use a lambda.

Answer (score 2):

You can chain the `where` clause:

`Person.where(name: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']).where('id >= ?', 42).first`

Answer (score 1):

The named scopes already proposed are pretty fine. The clasic way to do it would be:

```
names = ["dave", "jerry", "mike"]
date = DateTime.now
Person.find(:all, :conidtions => ["created_at > ? AND name IN ?", date, names])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm either going to use simple AR finders or [Searchgasm](http://www.binarylogic.com/2008/9/1/searchgasm-released).